# Jsonix - Error while unmarshalling element of file

Tags: node.js, xsd, xml-parsing, jsonix

I am trying to convert a xml file into a JSON object with a xsd schema. I am using nodeJS to do that. I have already created my mapping object but I keep getting this error: "(..) **could not be unmarshalled as is not known in this context and the property does not allow DOM content**."

Here is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Jsonix = require('jsonix').Jsonix;
var PO = require(__dirname + '/../mappings/PO').PO;

var context = new Jsonix.Context([PO]);
var unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.unmarshalFile(__dirname + '123456.xml', function (unmarshalled) {
    console.log(unmarshalled.value.author);
});
```

Here is a piece of the xsd schema (just the header definition):

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:editix="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
```

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the xml and the expected output?

Comment: We'd need to see your schema, mappings and the XML you're trying to unmarshal.

Comment: Problem was solved. Thanks for the answer. I had mapped the wrong xsd schema to the PO object.